# Read and print unicode strings

Tags: java, character-encoding, intellij-idea, javafx-2, system.out

I'm working on a program that is going to use lots of different languages and characters.

For example, I whould need to read a string with the german character ß from a file, and display the string properly on a JavaFX label, or print it to System.out.
My IDE suggests me to convert it to `\u00DF`, than it works properly, but I want to do it automatically.

Or make a string "ß" and display it properly.

How can I achieve my goal?

BTW, I'm using Intellij Idea.

EDIT:
When trying to compile the file manually, With UTF-8 W/O BOM (Validated through notepad++), I get the following error: [image: different encoding]
It seems that java trys to compile with Cp1255 for some reason.
Help?

Comment: I can't speak for IntelliJ, but in Eclipse and Maven, there's a source file encoding property. If you're reading from an Input Stream, you can wrap it in an input stream reader and specify the encoding there.

Comment: Intellij does have an encoding property. I have no experience in encoding what so ever, so I would be glad for a complete answer and an example.

Comment: What file type do you read this string from? Note that IDEA has a setting for transparent convertion in the `.properties` files, so that it will replace non-ascii characters with the Unicode escapes. For other files you can just use the UTF-8 encoding and it will work fine.

Comment: But System.out.println("ß"); displayes ֳ� and the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: And I'm using XML to read my data.

Comment: Please provide a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Just the simplest thing ever: System.out.println("ß"); in main, using UTF-8 without BOM desn't print correctly.

Comment: I would not ask for a project (JDK, OS, Encoding settings, compiler options, Run configuration) if it didn't work for me, but it [works fine out of the box on my system](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/2033/20121124235027.png).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following JVM arguements with the desired encoding value `-Dfile.encoding='your encoding'` 
This may not work all the time as it is set at the JVM startup. In that case if you are  encoding or decoding, you check the `file.encoding property` or `Charset.defaultCharset()` to find the current default encoding, and use the appropriate method overload or constructor overload to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

In the main class at the top add

```
static {
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "your-encoding");
}
```

Comment: What encoding to use in my case?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. No idea why.  System.out.println("ß"); displayes ֳ� and the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: This is because the font used in making consoles won't have unicode characters. Try displaying them in a JLabel.